# Measuring Dropped packets in Network through wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark

Monitoring the all network traffic from one port on the switch and captured the all traffic bu using wireshark.
Here i found all packet captured in the summary result and it has dropped packet information also. This is some thing lost packets in the network or at the wireshark point? 
I was in ambiguous...i am testing in ethernet based and TCP/IP based protocol.

One more possible case if my server is installed with wireshark and its capturing the all packets coming and going from this point. At this point also found the packet dropped in the wireshark summary. 
So any one help in this issue....any explanation appreciated.
thanks....
Chirug

Answer (score 0):

Surely wireshark is only telling you about packets *it* has dropped? I can't see how it could possibly know about any others.

Comment: But how it will tell when we run the same wireshark dump file in tcptrace is giving complete network characteristics information  from source to destination like delay, RTT, re transmistted packets,number of packet sent, etc...Almost its capturing the all the information from source to destination..if i have multiple clients and servers also its working in the same way.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of this response to my question. Wireshark can only see packets that are received at an interface it is sniffing. It can't see packets dropped before they get to that interface, because they're not there to be seen.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that, actually the port we are capturing with wireshark configured such a way that it should listen the complete network traffic on the network( Here one Hp switch was used for TCP/IP setup and this port was configured to listen the complete network traffic by using hyper terminal).

Comment: It still can't listen to packets that aren't there.